# How do you make a trigger to open an application when a print job passes through your driver? [C++] [WDK]

Tags: c++, printing, driver, wdk

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve functionality similar to what is done with Microsoft OneNote's "Send to OneNote" printer driver in Windows. Basically how that works is you create a document and print it through a "Send to OneNote 20xx" print queue. Once the job is spooled, Microsoft OneNote automatically opens and prompts the user for where they want to store the printed document within OneNote.

Its also important to point out that the port being used by the OneNote queue is "nul" - so it is not like a "print to file" queue like if the port were set to "FILE" or some specific PC location like a custom local port.

I also found a reference to [Virtual Queues in the driver INF file (PrintFax.Printer.Virtual)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/print/printer-inf-file-entries), which the Send to OneNote driver does use, but there is little actual information on how to further access this behavior in your code.

I've looked through a lot of documentation for V4 printer drivers but it feels like there are plenty of things missing or unexplained, this being one of them. If anyone has any info at all that might be useful it would be much appreciated.

Edit for clarification: So be clear, my question would be, what mechanism(s) can I use to replicate the behavior exhibited by the whole "Send to OneNote" print queue, where sending a job through a queue with my driver opens an external application and allows me to pass print data to it, rather than to a physical printer/fax/etc. machine?

Comment: exactly what is your question? please take a look at [tour] and [mcve].

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I edited my base question a bit to try to clarify but I know I'm asking a very general question. It's difficult to be more specific than that with what little working knowledge I have about drivers in general. How do I redirect a print job directly to an application. 
The DriverCategory field I provided a link to in my initial question appears to be something along the lines of what I am looking for but as you can see there isn't really much information on what exactly changing these values actually do or if there is any way to define behavior in the code based on how it is set.